# htaccess - wildcard for redirecting all humans.txt requests to single location

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'd like to redirect all requests for humans.txt (regardless of uri request) to the location of the humans.txt file (located in the top of the domain).

My logs aren't showing evidence of google.com/humans.txt, so it's not **that** problem. It's a simple exercise in reducing 404 errors, but I'm unsure whether to use filesmatch or rewritecond. I don't change things (or experiment) too often. The file is small and once accessed, would be cached locally, so in legitimate cases, ought to be 301 redirect to 304 'not modified' thereafter.

So if the request was www.pretendexample.com/about/humans.txt **or** www.pretendexample.com/news/humans.txt, both would redirect to www.pretendexample.com/humans.txt

I don't plan to have more than one humans.txt, and mod.rewrite is available. I prefer to use htaccess than other solutions.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do just the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.+humans\.txt$ /humans.txt [NC,QSA,L,R=301]
```

Put this in the beginning of your root .htaccess-file, and everything else (not ending on `humans.txt`) will be executed as before !

Comment: This code should be in the .htaccess file from your root domain. Please, put this in the beginning of the code. All the rest should still be working.

Comment: Ah ha! At the beginning of code, and it works. Will it prevent other code from working, in that case?

Comment: I'll do some further tests first, but so far so good. Will mark solved if good, after testing. :)) Cheers!

Comment: Alrighty. The placement of the code you provided was not the problem. The placement of the wordpress code: http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess was causing the problem. Said WP code has to be below your code. Other than that, perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_\/]+)humans.txt$ /humans.txt [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Tests result in 404s.

Comment: Yes. See recent reply.